# Excel VBA - set collection = nothing taking 100 times longer than creating collection

Tags: excel, vba

sorry if similar has already been posted - I couldn't find one.

I have a need to have a collection of classes that each contains a collection of classes. There's expected to be a few hundred thousand entries to the collections.

I am finding it's taking ~1 second to create all of the collections, but taking ~minutes to delete them afterwards.

Below is a snippet of random code that creates the issue I'm seeing.

Is this expected?  Why does it take ~100 times longer to delete the collections vs creating it. Is there any way of speeding it up?

Thanks

**Module1:**

```
Private p_main_collection As Collection

Sub main()

Debug.Print "Starting: " & Now()

    Set p_main_collection = New Collection

    Dim i As Long
    Dim j As Long

    Dim v_class1 As Class1
    Dim v_class2 As Class2

    For i = 1 To 8

        Set v_class1 = New Class1
        p_main_collection.Add v_class1

        v_class1.Num = i

        For j = 1 To 50000

            Set v_class2 = New Class2
            v_class2.Num = j

            v_class1.add_to_collection = v_class2

        Next j

    Next i

Debug.Print "Deleting: " & Now()
    Set p_main_collection = Nothing
Debug.Print "Deleted: " & Now()

End Sub
```

**Class1**

```
Private p_num As Integer
Private p_collection As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set p_collection = New Collection
End Sub

Public Property Let Num(p_num_in As Integer)
    p_num = p_num_in
End Property

Public Property Get Num() As Integer
    Num = p_num
End Property

Public Property Let add_to_collection(p_collection_in As Class2)
    p_collection.Add p_collection_in
End Property
```

**Class2**

```
Private p_num As Long

Public Property Let Num(p_num_in As Long)
    p_num = p_num_in
End Property

Public Property Get Num() As Long
    Num = p_num
End Property
```

**Result**

```
Starting: 08/01/2019 23:15:01
Deleting: 08/01/2019 23:15:02
Deleted: 08/01/2019 23:16:19
```

Comment: Why do you need to delete the collection? VBA should do garbage collection on unused items when they lose scope.

Comment: I don't necessarily need to delete it - but once my macro finishes running and I do my cleanup, that's when it locks up and takes a few minutes. Even when I leave it up to Excel to [STOP], it locks up for a few minutes emptying the collections.

Comment: I think you can safely skip this step, VBA should handle this for you.